# SDE and Stochastic calculus

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

$W_t$ is 1 dimension Brownian morion.

$X_t=(cosW_t,sinW_t)$

Write SDE about $X_t$

I thought that $f(t,x)=(cosx,sinx)$, but I can't how "$t$" is expressed.

I heard that the hint of this question is to use Ito formula.

Comment: If $f(t, x) = (\cos x, \sin x)$ then $X_t = f(t, W_t)$, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Outline**: Use Ito's formula to show that $$ d(\cos W_t) = -\sin W_t \,dW_t - \frac{1}{2} \cos W_t \,dt$$ and $$ d(\sin W_t) = \cos W_t \,dW_t - \frac{1}{2} \sin W_t \,dt.$$ From here, using standard SDE notation, $$ dX_t = (-\sin W_t, \cos W_t) \,dW_t - \frac{1}{2}(\cos W_t, \sin W_t) \,dt$$ hence $$ dX_t = A X_t \,dW_t - \frac{1}{2} X_t\, dt$$ where $$A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1\\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}.$$

Can you fill in the details?